# Managing remote DACLs on fileshares: Win32_ACE to Win32_Share

Tags: vbscript, wmi, share, windows-server-2003, dacl

Goal: Add a local user account share-level Read/Write permissions to an existing file share.

I'm hitting a roadblock in developing this. Apparently Microsoft wants you to add your user's ACE to the DACL and then back into the security descriptor of the share. (1). (No, NET SHARE /ADD is not available for existing shares, I was surprised.)

In theory that should be simple enough, but my main fear is doing it wrong and losing the existing share permissions (lots of network users, specific groups). This solution needs to scale to a few thousand shares. I'm developing the solution to output data about the existing DACL in case I need to back out. I should write code to interpret that log and be prepared to add them back en-masse should anything go wrong.

At the moment I'm using VBscript-- I feel PowerShell might be a bit stronger of an approach but VBscript/WMI is a known quantity.

Research:
(1) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/helloworld/archive/2008/07/22/editing-share-permission.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Copy the existing ACEs to an array:

```
rc = shareSec.GetSecurityDescriptor(sd)
ReDim acl(UBound(sd.DACL)+1)  '+1 for the new ACL we're going to add
For i = 0 To UBound(sd.DACL)
  Set acl(i) = sd.DACL(i)
Next
```

Add the new ACE to that array:

```
Set acl(UBound(acl)) = NewACE(NewTrustee(username, domain), 2032127)
```

The functions `NewTrustee()` and `NewACE()` encapsulate the instructions for creating the trustee and the ACE. The number is the access mask for *Full Control*.

Create a new security descriptor and assign it to the share:

```
Set sd = wmi.Get("Win32_SecurityDescriptor").SpawnInstance_
sd.ControlFlags = flags
sd.DACL = acl
rc = shareSec.SetSecurityDescriptor(sd)
```

Check [this page](https://secure.marumoto.us/motowiki/tiki-index.php?page=Reading+NTFS+and+Share+Permissions+with+VBScript+and+.Net) for a lot more detail information about security descriptors, trustees, ACLs and ACEs.

---

Full script:

```
Const FullControl = 2032127

' modify these variables according to your requirements:
computer = "."
share    = "..."
username = "..."
domain   = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserDomain

Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!//" _
  & computer & "/root/cimv2")
Set shareSec = GetObject("winmgmts:Win32_LogicalShareSecuritySetting.Name='" _
  & share & "'")

Function NewTrustee(name, domain)
  Dim trustee, account

  Set trustee = wmi.Get("Win32_Trustee").SpawnInstance_
  trustee.Name   = name
  trustee.Domain = domain
  Set account = wmi.Get("Win32_UserAccount.Domain='" & domain & "',Name='" _
    & name & "'")
  trustee.Properties_.Item("SID") = wmi.Get("Win32_SID.SID='" & account.SID _
    & "'").BinaryRepresentation

  Set NewTrustee = trustee
End Function

Function NewACE(trustee, permissions)
  Dim ace : Set ace = wmi.Get("Win32_Ace").SpawnInstance_
  ace.Properties_.Item("AccessMask") = permissions
  ace.Properties_.Item("AceFlags") = 3
  ace.Properties_.Item("AceType") = 0
  ace.Properties_.Item("Trustee") = trustee
  Set NewACE = ace
End Function

' copy existing ACEs
rc = shareSec.GetSecurityDescriptor(sd)
flags = sd.ControlFlags
ReDim acl(UBound(sd.DACL)+1)  '+1 for the new ACL we're going to add
For i = 0 To UBound(sd.DACL)
  Set acl(i) = sd.DACL(i)
Next
Set sd = Nothing

' add new ACE
Set acl(UBound(acl)) = NewACE(NewTrustee(username, domain), FullControl)

' prepare new security descriptor
Set sd = wmi.Get("Win32_SecurityDescriptor").SpawnInstance_
sd.ControlFlags = flags
sd.DACL = acl

' assign new security descriptor
rc = shareSec.SetSecurityDescriptor(sd)
```