# List and add NTFS permissions on shared folders

Tags: vbscript

Due to new domain migration, I need to find a script listing all NTFS permissions of groups and add a new permissions of the new group for some folders (these folders either CIFs or NFS).

Some folders have different groups and different permissions. such as pc\admin groups, now i need to add TA\admin groups to the same folder without deleting or wipe out the old permissions and groups.
I found a script but not listing any current permissions and groups:

Comment: thank you for your script but this can be run as vbs or PowerShell?

Do you think one script can do list all NTFS permissions and then add additional group for full access or RW access permissions? That would be a complicated script. I even don't know where to add servername and share names.

Comment: Then I suppose you need to hire someone to do the work. It certainly can be done in one script, but writing it in its entirety is leagues beyond the scope of SO. You could use my script [`AuditACLs.vbs`](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/auditacls.shtml) as a starting point and add code for [granting permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13341479/1630171) to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`icacls`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525.aspx) command to display or modify permissions on any given file or folder. For adding a missing group to a folder, something like this should work:

```
Set sh  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

fldr  = "C:\some\folder"
group = "TA\admin"

rc = sh.Run("%COMSPEC% /c icacls """ & fldr & """ | find /i """ & group _
  & """", 0, True)
If rc <> 0 Then sh.Run "icacls """ & fldr & """ /grant " & group & ":F"
```

For listing the permissions on a folder tree something like [`ntfsacls`](http://www.coopware.in2.info/_ntfsacl.htm) or [`AuditACLs.vbs`](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/auditacls.shtml) might be a better choice, though.

---

`icacls` usage example:

```
icacls "C:\some\folder" /grant FOO\bar:(OI)(CI)RX Administrators:(OI)(CI)F
```

This will grant the group "bar" of the domain "FOO" read/execute permissions and the local group "Administrators" full access to the folder "C:\some\folder" and all of its subfolders that are configured to inherit permissions from their parent.

To run this command from VBScript with variables for the folder and groups you'd do this:

```
fldr = "C:\some\folder"
groupA = "FOO\bar"
groupB = "Administrators"

Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

sh.Run "icacls """ & fldr & """ /grant " & groupA & ":(CI)(OI)RX " _
  & groupB & ":(CI)(OI)F"
```

Comment: Thank you for your script.This is vbs or power shell.

Comment: """ is the place to place folder name or server name or group name. I just need one example with server or folder name in the vbs. Thanks!!

Comment: Ansgar: your script is working but it is not populate the permission to the first sub folder and second sub-folders.

Comment: Change `F` to `(OI)(CI)F` to make the permissions inheritable.

Comment: It works after change to----If rc <> 0 Then sh.Run "icacls """ & fldr & """ /grant " & group & ":(OI)(CI)F" but how to add mutiple groups at the same times , not one group at one time.

Comment: well, I see a lot of information but none of talking about multiple entries.. I need to enter more groups and strings to test by myself since none of forum talking about multiple group entries. .

Comment: `ICACLS name [/grant[:r] Sid:perm[...]] ...`. The `[...]` means you can add more identifier:permission pairs after the first one: `icacls folder /grant userA:M groupB:RX Administrators:F`

Comment: you are much helpful than others in other forums. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did I do correctly? It didn't work when I add more groups using the same pattern:      sh.Run "icacls """ & fldr & """ /grant " & groupA & ":(CI)(OI)RX " _
  & groupB & ":(CI)(OI)F" _ & groupC & ":(CI)(OI)F" _ " & groupD & ":(CI)(OI)RX"

Comment: The `_` is a line continuation character. You put it at the end of a line when you want to continue an instruction on the next line. Only then. Only there. Also, there's a spurious double quote before the `& groupD`.

Comment: yes, I did try that but just won't work but it works fine after deleted my add-on. does it need to be on next line? How about adding more folders: c:\folder1; c:\fodler2, C:\folder3 and excute the same permission

Comment: How about actually trying things yourself before asking a question? `icacls` takes a single file or folder name, so you need to run the command for each folder.

Comment: Thank you, you are right but I did try it , not working . I thought you know much better than I do.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: "Not working" is an insufficient problem description. Also, >10 comments means either your question seriously needs clarification or you're moving the target. I suggest you update your question with the code you're currently using and explain how *exactly* it's "not working" (i.e. how the results you get are different from the results you expected).

Comment: Set sh  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
fldr = "d:\folder1"
groupA = "win\xxxxxx"
groupB = "Administrators"
groupC = "domain\userA"
groupD = "domain\userB"


Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

sh.Run "icacls """ & fldr & """ /grant " & groupA & ":(CI)(OI)RX " _
  & groupB & ":(CI)(OI)F" _ " & groupC & ":(CI)(OI)RX" _ " & groupD & ":F"

Comment: Which part of "update your **question**" wasn't clear enough? Code posted in comments is next to useless, because it can't be formatted properly.

Comment: I just wonder why it didn't work even I used the exactly same pattern as you did. I could not add permissions when I add two more groups but it worked fine after I removed 3rd and 4th groups so I wonder icacls tool cannot handle more than two groups, maybe.

Thanks!